# Equation of a Circle which share the same center

Tags: conic-sections

How to find the equation of the circle which passes through the point $(-2,-4)$ and has the same center as the circle whose equation is $x^2+ y^2 -4x - 6y -23$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Complete the squares of $$x^2 + y^2 - 4x - 6y - 23 = 0$$ to find it's center. (See the formula for the equation of a circle with radius r and center $(a, b)$, below.) Once you complete the squares for the given circle and obtain that form, you can "read off" the center of both circles.

$$x^2 - 4x + 4  + y^2 - 6y + 9  = 23 + 4 + 9 \iff (x-2)^2 + (y-3)^2 = 36 = 6^2$$

So the center of the circle is $(2, 3)$.

Then use your given point, along with the center you find, to compute the distance from the center to $(-2, -4)$, which will give you the desired circle's radius. If $(a, b)$ is the center of your circle, then $$r = \sqrt{(a - (-2))^2 + (b - (-4))^2}$$

That means the radius of our desired circle is given by $$r = \sqrt{(2 - (-2))^2 + (3 - (-4))^2} = \sqrt{4^2 + 7^2} = \sqrt{16 + 49} = \sqrt{65}$$

Then use the standard form for an equation of a circle to construct the equation of your desired circle: $r:$ radius, $(a, b):$ center gives us $$(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 = r^2$$

> $$(x - 2)^2 + (y - 3)^2 = 65$$

Comment: Yes I have done with this like center will be (-2,-3). Right? Finding the radius i will use distance formula for example: r^2 = (-2+2)^2+(-3+4)^2 = 1.. but this is not the answer.\

Comment: Your center is off: Center = (2, 3). Now can you finish it?

Comment: But amWhy its -ve. while comparing with the general equation of the circle.. I am just confuse why we are neglecting the -ve signs

Comment: I am not neglecting any negative signs. The equation of a circle with center $(a, b)$ is given by $(x - a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2$. The x-coordinate of the center is *subtracted* from $x$, then squared and the $y$ coordinate of the center is *subtracted* from $y$ and then squared.  If you have an equation like $$(x+a)^2 + (y + b)^2 = (x - (-a))^2 + (y - (-b))^2 = r^2$$ then your center is $(-a, -b)$. But in this case, we have positive x and y coordinates for the center.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Simply leave unchanged everything except the constant term. Substitute $x=-2$, $y=-4$ to find it.

Comment: Very good answer!

Answer (score 0):

the equation of a circle is $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$ so get your equation to look like $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=23$ then the center of the circle is (a,b) and the equation of the circle you want is $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=R^2$ where R is the distance from the center to (-2,-4)

Answer (score 0):

Take your existing circle and find its center *C*, by differentiating the equation by $x$ and by $y$

$$ \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}(x^2+ y^2 -4x - 6y -23) = 0 \\\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}y}(x^2+ y^2 -4x - 6y -23) = 0 $$

$$ 2x_c-4=0 \\ 2y_c-6=0 $$

$$ x_c = 2 \\ y_c = 3 $$

Find the radius from the distance between *C* and your point *A* = (-2,-4)

$$ r = \sqrt{ ((-2)-2)^2 + (-4-3)^2 } = \sqrt{65} $$

Your equation is

$$ \boxed{ (x-x_c)^2 + (y-y_c)^2 - r^2 = 0 }$$

Comment: Thanks ja72... Indeed good done..