# Formula for area of intersection of cone and plane, given their Cartesian equations.

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, 3d, area

Prove that the area of the section of the cone $bc x^2+ca y^2+ab z^2=0$ obtained as the intersection with the plane $lx+my+nz=p$ is $$ \frac{\pi p^2 \sqrt{abc}}{{(al^2+bm^2+cn^2)}^{3/2}}.$$

Comment: Why should I prove that?

Comment: @anomaly Because math.stackexchange is a machine that solves math problems. We are chips of this machine, we have Artificial(?) Intelligence and we work in parallel.

Comment: @ajotatxe: The point of this site is not to solve people's homework problems for them, or to act as a crowd-sourced version of Mathematica. I'm happy to help people; I'm happy to answer questions; I'm happy to discuss the material; but I'm not happy to write an answer for a question that's been lazily dumped here, with any effort or context or elaboration. Now, that's my chip; you're certainly free to use yours however you like.

Comment: @anomaly I was being sarcastic. I 100% agree with you.

Comment: It is interesting that there is such a simple formula for the answer.  I would be happy to see a solution, or to write one myself if I have time to solve the problem.

Comment: To write the equation of a cone $pX^2+qY^2+rZ^2=0$ in the given form, it is necessary that $pqr > 0$, by multiplying the equation with -1 if necessary.

Comment: @ajotatxe: It's hard to pick up sarcasm in text, or maybe that's just me. :) (I also saw the +1 to the post and assumed it was yours.)

Comment: My approach: putting value of z from equation of plane into equation of cone to get the equation of required section  and then i can find its area. Is there any other method to find the area of cross section

Answer (score 3):

We assume that $n\not=0$. By letting $z=(p-(lx+my))/n$ in $bc x^2+ca y^2+ab z^2=0$, we find the equation of the orthogonal projection on the $xy$ plane of the intersection curve: the conic
$$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$
where
$$A:= abl^2+cbn^2\;,\;
B := 2ablm\;,\;
C := abm^2+can^2\\
D := -2abpl\;,\;
E := -2abpm\;,\;
F := abp^2.$$
Now if this conic is an ellipse (that is when $4AC-B^2>0$), then the area of intersection of cone and plane is
$$\mbox{area}=\int_{\Omega}\sqrt{1+\frac{l^2+m^2}{n^2}}dxdy=\frac{1}{|n|}\sqrt{l^2+m^2+n^2}\cdot|\Omega|.$$
where $\Omega$ is the inside of the ellipse. 
According to [Calculating the length of the semi-major axis from the general equation of an ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227369/calculating-the-length-of-the-semi-major-axis-from-the-general-equation-of-an-el?noredirect=1&lq=1) , the area of this ellipse, which is $\pi$ times the product of the semi-major axis and the semi-minor axis, is
$$|\Omega|=
\frac{2\pi\left(\frac{AE^2{-}BDE{+}CD^2}{4AC{-}B^2}-F\right)}{\sqrt{4AC-B^2}}.
$$
Now it turns out that 
$$\mbox{area}=\frac{\pi p^2 \sqrt{l^2+m^2+n^2}\sqrt{|abc|}}{ |al^2+bm^2+cn^2|^{3/2}}.$$

P.S. The above formula si "dimensionally correct". On the other hand, if in the formula stated in the question our formula is not correct. we double the coefficients of the plane then the numerator is multiplied by $2^2=4$ and the denominator by $(2^2)^{3/2}=8$.

Comment: @Asif Khan My formula is different from yours.  Are you sure that your formula is correct?

Comment: the textbook answer is same as given in question however Is there any  other method like vector calculus to verify it.

Comment: @Asif Khan Your formula is not correct. If you double the coefficients of the plane then the numerator is multiplied by $2^2=4$ and the denominator by $(2^2)^{3/2}=8$.

Comment: @Asif Khan I made an error in the previous formula. Now it is symmetric (as it should be) and correct (I hope).